How to debug a Meta System-user access token
I'm having an issue that when I try to use the debug_token?input_token={} endpoint for meta graph api, I get a permissions error if I use a System-User access token to try to debug that very same token.
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) You must provide an app access token, or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "XYZ123DOREMI"
  }
}

I have an app where I ask the user to generate a System User Token and I can't seem to use that token with the debug endpoint to actually see the specifications of the token/ ensure it was generated properly and know when it will expire.

I am able to get the debug endpoint to work only if I use a different access token such as a user access token. Is there anyway to fix this? Maybe it is missing permissions on the system user token?

Did you manage to fix this? I am facing the same error.
